# Cannot add one more entities in terms of equals and hashcode in Spring Boot in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a problem about adding one more genres in Movie Entity. As I have a problem about updating movie in terms of updated genres as shown as new values. That's why I use `equals` and `hashcode` in all entities which are named for Genre, Director and lastly Movie.

I used to build it in `Intellij IDEA`

However, I show only first genre while adding one more when I call `getMovieById` and `updateMovieById`.

How can I fix the issue?

Here is my project link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springboothazelcast)

Here is my equals and hashcode method for Genre,Movie and Director. I only add Genre's one.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Genre)) return false;
        Genre genre = (Genre) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), genre.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
```

Here is my test class which is shown below.

```
@Test
    void createMovie() throws ParseException {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setName("Movie A");
        movie.setRating(7.5);

        Director movieDirector = new Director();
        movieDirector.setName("Director 1");
        movie.setDirector(movieDirector);

        Genre genreFirst = new Genre();
        genreFirst.setName("Adventure");
        genreFirst.setMovie(movie);

        Genre genreSecond = new Genre();
        genreSecond.setName("Action");
        genreSecond.setMovie(movie);

        movie.addGenre(genreFirst);
        movie.addGenre(genreSecond);

        Movie createdMovie = movieService.save(movie);
        System.out.println("createdMovie Id : " + createdMovie.getId());

        assertThat(createdMovie.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }
```

**Edit**

Here is my updateMovieById which is shown below.

```
@Test
    void updateMovieById() throws ParseException {

    createMovie();

    Long id = 1L;
    Movie movie = movieService.findById(id).get();

    movie.setName("Movie B");
    movie.setRating(7.5);

    Director movieDirector = new Director();
    movieDirector.setName("Director 2");
    movie.setDirector(movieDirector);

    LocalDate now = Utils.formatDate(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.JANUARY, 1));
    movie.setCreatedAt(now);

    Genre genreFirst = new Genre();
    genreFirst.setName("Historical");
    genreFirst.setMovie(movie);

    Genre genreSecond = new Genre();
    genreSecond.setName("Horror");
    genreSecond.setMovie(movie);

    movie.addGenre(genreFirst);
    movie.addGenre(genreSecond);

    Movie updatedMovie = movieService.update(id,movie);


    assertThat(updatedMovie.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
}
```

When I update movie, the genres are listed as shown below. How can I fix that issue?

```
MovieService | update | Movie Genre : Adventure
MovieService | update | Movie Genre : Action
MovieService | update | Movie Genre : Historical
MovieService | update | Movie Genre : Horror
```

Comment: @RamanSahasi How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are storing the `Genre` in a `Set` inside the `Movie` class.

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Genre> genres = new HashSet<>();
```

As long as the `Genre` instances are not saved in the database, their `id` is still `null`, so the equals/hashcode implementation will see them as equal and only 1 of them remains in the `Set` (a `Set` does not allow duplicates).

If you want to keep the fact that the id is assigned by the database, then you need to implement equals and hashcode like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Genre gene = (Genre) o;
        return id != null &&
                id.equals(genre.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return getClass().hashCode();
    }
```

See [How to implement equals and hashCode using the JPA entity identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/)for more info or [Equals and hashcode implementation considerations](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/26/equals-and-hashcode-implementation-considerations/) for a broader discussion.

An alternative implementation is using early primary key generation where you first generate the primary key and pass it in the constructor manually.

Comment: I updated my post. This method only works for creating movie. What about others. When I update it, I have an issue. How can I fix it?

Comment: The problem is exactly the same. You need to update your implementation of equals and hashcode to what I have showed for all your entity classes.

Comment: @WinDeblauwe. I wrote the code which is based on your view. I implement all functions to other entities but the issue still exists. I cannot update movie. Can you look through my respository again. Can you run it in Intellij IDEA?

Comment: You did not update the `hashCode` method. Can you do that and try again?

Comment: @WinDeblauwe I tried it but `updateMovieById` cannot work flawlessly. Although there are `2` genres listed from movie, I get `4` genre values. I showed it into the log result. How can I fix it?

Comment: It is normal if you add 2 genres in `createMovie()` and another 2 genres in `updateMovieById()` that you end up with 4 genres.

Comment: But I want to replace genres which I define in `updateMovieById()` with previous ones. I get only `2` updated genres of movie at last. How can I do that?

Comment: You can add a method `removeAllGenres()` to remove the previous genres maybe? But this is no longer related to your question. Best to open a separate question if you have a specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I fixed it. I updated my repository. Can you look through it once more to determine if it right?